# Windows Media Player default grayed-out on Windows 7 Professional

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player, file-association

On my Windows 7 machine if I i go to Default Programs, all the media files are associated to Windows Media Player and the association check-boxes are grayed-out. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it in Windows. You can only un-associate a default program by associating it with another default program.

You can do this with [**Default Programs Editor**](http://defaultprogramseditor.com) though. Any check box can be un-checked.

[image: Default Programs Editor can un-associate programs that are grayed out in Windows]

Answer (score 1):

The checkboxes are disables because you cannot unassociate Windows Media Player or any other application really. To change the default to another application, you select that application and select which files it should be associated with.